# Multiple natural joins in a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have three tables: Orders, Items and Items_Orders.  There is a many-to-many relationship between Items and Orders implemented by the Items_Orders table.  I am trying to perform a query which does a natural join on all three tables (to see which items are in each order).

Here is the SQL code I currently have:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders 
WHERE customer= 'username' NATURAL JOIN Items_Orders NATURAL JOIN Items
```

However, I am getting a very non-descript error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NATURAL JOIN Items_Orders NATURAL JOIN Items'
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Natural joins are not a SQL standard so I would avoid using them. This will create lock in on the MySQL/MariaDB platform.  Use a INNER JOIN instead.

Comment: You probably shouldn't just make up syntax. Might be here a while.

Comment: I believe you would also need to tell it what columns to join on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM Orders NATURAL JOIN Items_Orders NATURAL JOIN Items
WHERE customer= 'username'
```